# Content-adressed storage that can deal with a decentral network of repositories (git-annex without git)

Tags: file-synchronization, version-control

git-annex is an awesome program. If I have a version-controlled computational biology analysis, it keeps track of my large (tens of GB) result files that I do not want to check into git because

1. I do not want my git repo to become that large for speed reasons
2. I do not want to keep these results forever but delete them when the underlying models are improved, in contrast to my code that is version-controlled like usual
3. I still want my version control system to quickly check out the results (if they still exist) along with a certain code version so I cannot just .gitignore the results.
4. I want to keep track of other places (input folder of other analysis, public repositories, folders of colleagues) where some of the results are copied to (e.g. my repo is cloned there as a submodule).
5. Available information is exchanged peer-to-peer, without having a central authority, as I do not have the resources to manage that.

Git-annex can do all of this very nicely by basically replacing the files by symlinks to `.git/annex/objects/HASH...`, however, it does have its downsides:

1. It is complicated to use for non-technical people, has a few quirks (e.g. it thinks by default that all files that start with a "." are git settings files (so it thinks `.local/` is something like `.gitmodules`), and it prints git error messages that are not helpful for biologists that have a few years of self-taught scripting experience
2. It causes problems with Windows because of its extremely long file names (it repeats the file hash in the name and the enclosing directory!)
3. It is restricted to git which precludes us from testing other version control systems that might maybe require less technical knowledge than git, like mercurial, or sometimes just [folders with time stamps](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pcbi.1005510).
4. It is originally a backup system so it favours use cases that keep folders completely in sync in its user experience

I think the system must only be able to:

1. Replace a file by a symlink to a content-adressed storage (folder where files are named by their checksum)
2. Keep track of which files are available in the local storage
3. Exchange updates with other repositories about which files are available where
4. Potentially send and receive files from other repositories

Which program can do this while being version control system agnostic?